# How to format Body of Jenkins emal which is taken from text file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-email-ext

I have created a jenkins job in which it will send the mail notification and I tried to embed the content of text file to body of email.

```
<b><font color="black">BUILD :</font> <font color="green">$PROJECT_NAME - $BUILD_STATUS </font> </b> <BR>
<BR>
<BR>

<div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
${FILE,path="gitlog.txt"}
</div>

<BR>
<BR>
<BR>

-BAT DevOps Team <BR>
<BR>_____________________________________________________________________<BR>

<font color="#808080">Note: This is a System Generated Mail. We request you not to reply to this message.</font><BR>
<BR>
<BR>
```

The Output of Jenkins mail is :[image: Jenkins Mail Output]

output of the mail is not in readable format. How to format?

How to use Groovy script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the content in [pre tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

```
<pre>content</pre>
```